# how to declare JSON datatype as input in plsql procedure

Tags: plsql

```
create or replace procedure sp_json_(IN data JSON,input2 In varchar2, output out varchar2 )
is 

name varchar2(20);
age varchar2;
occ varchar2(20);
begin

set name = json_unquote(json_extract(data,'$.name'));
set age = json_unquote(json_extract(data,'$.age'));
set occ = json_unquote(json_extract(data,'$.occ'));

if ( input2 = 'name') then 
    output := name
elsif ( input2 = 'age') then
    output := age
elsif(input2 = 'occ') then
    output := occ
end if;

end;
/
```

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IN" when expecting one of the following:          current delete exists prior. here im getting error like this when i execute. how to solve this error.

Comment: What is the database ? pl/sql is for oracle but functions "json_unquote" and "json_extract" are not oracle syntax.

Comment: what json format we use for plsql

Comment: pls confirm the database and version

Comment: oracle database version 21C

Comment: JSON datatype is new in 21C - I don't have a db available to test this on. But your code is full of syntax errors. The particular error you're getting is because of the "(IN data JSON..." - that is not a correct syntax.

Comment: Please see the [PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference for 21c database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/json-types.html). It has examples of parsing JSON in a 21c database using PL/SQL.